# trying to make a simple image gallery with popup bootstrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple image gallery with 100x100 thumbnails and using bootstrap popup to view every image in its full size when you click it.

```
<?php
$eventFiles1 = scandir($eventDir);
$eventFiles = array_diff($eventFiles1, array('.', '..'));

foreach($eventFiles as $eventFile)
{
    $image = "./".$eventDir."/".$eventFile;

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

    if($width > $height)
    {
        ?>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href=""><div style="height:100px;width:100px;margin:10px;background-color:black;display:inline-block;background-position:center;background-image:url('<?php echo $image; ?>');background-size:auto 100%;"></div></a>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href=""><div style="height:100px;width:100px;margin:10px;background-color:black;display:inline-block;background-position:center;background-image:url('<?php echo $image; ?>');background-size:100% auto;"></div></a>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

As it is now, it doesn't work the way I want it. I'll explain why:

say my gallery contains 5 images (image1.jpeg, image2.jpeg......image5.jpeg)
no matter which image I click to enlarge, the image appearing in the modal is always image1.jpeg.

Now, I did believe the problem to be that my model always has the same ID - `#myModal`, but even when I tried giving it a dynamic ID by for example changing the ID `divModal` to `$image`, but this did not work either - it resulted in nothing happening at all when I click the images.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put a different id to your modal and to link

```
foreach($eventFiles as $key => $eventFile)
```

and for html

```
data-target="#myModal'.$key.'"

<div id="myModal'.$key.'" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Wow, I couldn't believe the solution would be that small and simple, but in the end it was. >.< Thank you!